# pass argument to matlab function from C#

Tags: c#, matlab, process

I want to execute matlab function in C#.
I write this matlab function.

```
function []= f(input)
save('D:\test.txt','input','-ASCII');
end
```

then by "deploytool" create exe file form this matlab code.

I try run the exe file in C#.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {


        string fileName = @"D:\test.exe";  //address of exe file
        Process p = new Process();
        p.StartInfo.FileName = fileName;
        int[][] d = new int[2][];
        for(int i = 0 ; i< d.Length;i++)
        {
            d[i] = new int[3];
            for(int j = 0 ; j < d[0].Length;j++)
                d[i][j] = i + j;
        }
        p.StartInfo.Arguments = d.ToString();
        p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
        p.Start();
        p.WaitForExit();
    }
```

but saved text file contains :

```
8.3000000e+01   1.2100000e+02   1.1500000e+02   1.1600000e+02   1.0100000e+02           1.0900000e+02   4.6000000e+01   7.3000000e+01   1.1000000e+02   1.1600000e+02   5.1000000e+01   5.0000000e+01   9.1000000e+01   9.3000000e+01   9.1000000e+01   9.3000000e+01
```

please help me.

Comment: Somehow I doubt that your MATLAB code actually saved the file you show us. Please verify.

Comment: saved file exactly this I write. only in first is some space

Answer (score 0):

Check [Documentation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_external/call-matlab-function-from-a-c-client.html)

I Hope this helps.